# How to Setup VS Code For C++ 14 /C ++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I tried to run a .cpp file from workspace but giving me this error about not adding c++11/higher flags but I have added them in task.json

**Error**

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\"main
main.cpp:8:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
using ordered_set = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
^
main.cpp:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
using ordered_set_rev = tree<T, null_type, greater<T>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
^
main.cpp:12:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
using dijkstra = priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>;
^
main.cpp:62:31: warning: variadic templates only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
template <typename T, typename... Args>
                               ^
main.cpp:63:52: warning: variadic templates only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
void err(istream_iterator<string> it, T a, Args... args) {
```

**Task.Json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "test",
                "-std=c++14",
                "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\"main
main.cpp:8:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
 using ordered_set = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
 ^
main.cpp:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
 using ordered_set_rev = tree<T, null_type, greater<T>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
 ^
main.cpp:12:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
 using dijkstra = priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>;
 ^
main.cpp:62:31: warning: variadic templates only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 template <typename T, typename... Args>
                               ^
main.cpp:63:52: warning: variadic templates only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 void err(istream_iterator<string> it, T a, Args... args) {
```

c_cpp_properties:

```
    {

        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "compilerPath": "F:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17"
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that is the correct `tasks.json`? it doesn't match the error message

Comment: Yes It was working fine . Then I re installed windows and vs code but then it's not working for some reason. Task. json was in the folder from the beginning...

Comment: I second Alan's comment. The build output
`[Running] cd "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\Nuhash\Desktop\test\"main`
does not match your `tasks.json`.

Comment: Yes But Tasks.json is correct. Dont know why command isn't matching with the tasks.json i recreated it several times. Anyway i fixed it with changing code runner config in  settings.json

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I added code runner and added this in settings.json Seems to work for me :D

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
},
```

Comment: Code runner is an extension with very limited functionality, not useful for even most basic C++ development. Don't use it.

Comment: @n.m. question was about running a single .cpp file. To run single file is most cases code runner is useful

Answer (score 5):

Add `"-std=c++11",` to the `"args"` value in your `task.json` file. That should resolve your c++11 issue. 
So finally your task.json will look like

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",                
                "-std=c++11",
                "-std=c++14",
                "main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "test"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @uma_8331 You can press Ctrl+Shift+P and choose "Tasks:  Configure Task" and VSCode will create one for you

Answer (score 4):

- Open VS Code
- Go to the extensions (Ctrl +Shift + X)
- Then Simply click on the code runner
- Then click on the settings icon there
- Then choose Extension Settings
- [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjI6.png)

> 

- Settings will open up,
- Click on the edit in settings.json under Code-Runner -Executer Map
- [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkvUz.png)

> 

- Find the "cpp" in the json file and add -std=c++17 after && g++
- Finally it will look like this "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
- Save it and you are all done]
- [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ja1.png)

> 

- Try this code out if this code runs without any error you have enabled C++17
  [Link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2VFK04S9Lk)

> 

- Make sure that when you run the code terminal look like this
- [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nTg3.png)
- **Note:** If you don't use code Runner I will advise you to do so

  > 
- If you are using windows and your Compiler don't support c++17
- You can install the MinGw latest compiler(9.2.0) from the below link
- [Link](https://nuwen.net/files/mingw/mingw-17.1.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Set `cppStandard` to `c++17` or `c++14` respectively.

You need the C++ extension for that https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools

Comment: I already have that extension and cppStandard is set to c++17

Answer (score 0):

I didn't added MinGW header files in c_cpp_properties.json .
After It worked fine
c_cpp_properties.json lookes like this ...

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe\"",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

and change my tasks.json to this ...

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "g++.exe -std=c++14 -g ${file} -o ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe && ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
]
}
```

now it builds and runs the compiled file