# Error when compiling in coderunner vscode

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I use Code Runner installed in VS Code to run my C++ code, but it just can't run in c++11 style so it always appears c++11 errors and warnings, how can i do to make it available to c++ 11 ?

Comment: How did you  verify that the errors and warnings do not occur simply because the code you try to run contains syntax errors etc? Can you run a confirmed error-free HelloWorld?

Answer (score 0):

For enabling C++11 on coderunner(vscode) please check if the setting has it enabled.

Go to

> Settings > User Settings

In here, search for

> Run Code Configuration:

In the menu find: `"code-runner.executorMap"`

Then edit the setting by adding it to User Setting as below for C++11 support: 
*`"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++11 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"`*

Hope this helps !

For more help check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116344/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-c-14-c-17)