# c++ compile error 'expected ';' at end of declaration' when using direct brace initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, c++17

I'm very new to C++, working through my first tutorial, and when I try to compile code from the lesson, I get the following error:

```
expected ';' at end of declaration
    int x{ }; // define variable x to hold user input (a...
         ^
         ;
```

The full code for the program I'm attempting to run:

```
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout and std::cin
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x{ }; 
    std::cin >> x; 
    std::cout << "You entered " << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code (v.1.46.1) on a Macbook Pro, with the Microsoft C/C++ extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

My compiler is Clang:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Initially, I ran Terminal > Configure Default Build Task in VS Code to create a .vscode/tasks.json compiler settings file. That file currently looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        // Set C++ Standards 
        "-std=c++17",

        // Increase compiler warnings to maximum
        "-Wall",
        "-Weffc++",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Wsign-conversion",

        // Treat all warnings as errors
        "-Werror",

        // Disable compiler extensions
        "-pedantic-errors",

        // File to compile
        "-g",
        "${file}",

        // Output file
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the `-std=c++17` flag set, which should allow direct brace initialization from what I understand.

I'm not sure it matters, since I'm trying to compile and not build/debug, but for the sake of thoroughness, I also have a .vscode/launch.json file with the following contents:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why `int x{ };` is not working properly to intitialize the variable and what I can do to fix it so it will work?

[Edit]: Further settings I've checked/tested:

- Code compiles correctly when running compile directly from command line with `clang++ -std=c++17 -g helloworld.cpp -o helloworld`
- VS Code C/C++ extension configuration has setting 'C++ standard' set to c++17 (seems to be the default). Even so, running command-line compile without `-std=c++17` flag set causes same compiler error.
- Tried changing `int x{ };` to the following:

  - `int x( );`: fails with a very long list of errors
  - `int x(0);`: compiles successfully
  - `int x = { };`: compiles successfully
  - `int x = {0};`: compiles successfully
  - `int x;': compiles successfully
  - `int x = 0;': compiles successfully

Comment: Can you compile it on the command line, or does that also produce an error?

Comment: What's the name of your source file, including the extension?  clang deduces the language from the filename, and it's possible it thinks this is something other than C++.  Also, are there any other errors besides the one shown?

Comment: @ChrisMM yes it does compile from the command line with

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wsign-conversion -Werror -pedantic-errors -g helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

It also compiles just fine when I remove all the optional flags on the command line, like so:
```
clang++ -std=c++17 -g helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

Comment: @NateEldredge source file is called `helloworld.cpp`. This is the only error I get. Full console output is:


```
Executing task: /usr/bin/clang++ -g /Users/{redacted}/Documents/development/c++/learncpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp -o /Users/{redacted}/Documents/development/c++/learncpp/helloworld/helloworld <

/Users/{redacted}/Documents/development/c++/learncpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:6:10: error: 
      expected ';' at end of declaration
    int x{ }; 
         ^
         ;
1 error generated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: The `-std=c++17` is obviously not being passed, and your compiler is old enough to default to C++03, where that syntax doesn’t work.

Comment: @DavisHerring c++03 would not compile `int x = {0};`

Comment: Are you sure this is a real compilation error and not some kind of instant syntax assistant message?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: C++03 [does allow](https://www.godbolt.org/z/iERC9Z) that syntax ([dcl.init]/13); the braces are ignored.

Comment: @DavisHerring what about `int x={};`? Anyway the compiler is based on llvm9 which is not old enough to default to c++03.

Comment: perhaps /usr/bin/clang++ is not the version you run from the command line?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. in C++03 and in C, a scalar may be initialized by `=` with a single expression in braces.  The C++11 extensions included empty braces, and omitting the `=` symbol

Comment: @M.Layton the "full console output" you posted in comments shows that your expected flags are not passed, so this is a problem with vscode configuration (not with your program)

Comment: Does it compile on the command like without ` -std=c++17`? The version of clang is new enough to default to c++14 I think...

Comment: solution for this problem is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116344/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-c-14-c-17

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and there was an error in my tasks.json.  This worked for me, try it:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: The missing line is probably `"-std=c++17",`

Comment: @Yar that line is not missing from the question post.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, I tried to modify tasks.json, c_cpp_properties.json and settings.json but nothing worked. I finally tried the solution shown [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3005#issuecomment-455418331), which is to disable the C/C++ Clang Command Adapter extension, and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [this explanation of List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), this syntax should be legal since c++11:

```
int main()
{
    int n0{};     // value-initialization (to zero)
    int n1{1};    // direct-list-initialization
    //...
}
```

I attempted to compile your code in my local environment and all worked fine:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wsign-conversion -Werror -pedantic-errors ...

clang++ --version
clang version 9.0.1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Maybe you used some similar ';' character which is not ASCII?
I attempted to use a Chinese character '；' instead and get this:

```
fly.cc:32:13: error: treating Unicode character <U+FF1B> as identifier character rather than as ';' symbol [-Werror,-Wunicode-homoglyph]
    int x{ }； 
            ^~
fly.cc:32:13: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int x{ }； 
            ^
            ;
```

Comment: That's not actually a Chinese character, just a [fullwidth](https://unicodeplus.com/block/FF00) semicolon...

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a while as well. Here is the command that got it working for me:

`clang++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld -std=c++17 && "<YOUR PATH TO THE FILE INSIDE THE QUOTES>"helloworld`

E.g. `"< YOUR PATH TO THE FILE INSIDE THE QUOTES >" = "/Users/< your username >/<something else>/"helloworld`

I also installed the extension `code runner` and then searched in settings for `run in terminal` then checked the box which said `Code-runner: Run in terminal`.

You should also be able to search for `C++` in the settings as well and then set a default Cpp standard, but this never worked for me so I had to add it in the command.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem with code runner, the problem is that we do not specify to code runner which version to use, for that, go to the installed `extensions > code runner > extension configuration > edit` in `settings.json`
look in **code-runer.executorMap**:

the line that says cpp in my case is on line of code 21. after `$filename` you put `-std=c++17`

```
// It should look similar to this
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -std=c++17 -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
```

It worked for me and solved that problem, c++17 depends on the version of the compiler