# Initialising variables in C++ with {}

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, initialization, clang

I am using C++ in Visual Studio Code. When I want to initialise a variable I cannot initialise it with {} (e.g., int x {0};). Instead, I have to use () (e.g., int x (0);).

The error I get when using {} is "error: expected ';' at end of declaration" Although I have put ; at the end of declaration.

I'm using clang 11.0.0 as the compiler. Is it related to the compiler?

The code runs through the terminal by ./filename command. However, it gives errors when running by coderunner extension in VSCode.

Comment: You compiling with C++11 onwards?

Comment: Are you on macOS?

Comment: @LouisCloete The question is tagged "macos" so yes....

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't know the version of C++. I'm new to C++. How can I find out its version?

Comment: @LouisCloete yes

Comment: @Fareanor I saw that, I just make sure. I've seen more mis-tagged questions than I care to remember...

Comment: @negarpourmoazemi look at this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_build-helloworldcpp and try to add `"-std=c++17"` to your `tasks.json`

Comment: Relevant, possibly a duplicate: [c++ compile error 'expected ';' at end of declaration' when using direct brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62487546/580083).

Comment: I do think it is a duplicate. Try to look at your launch.json and compare it carefully to the one at the link @Daniel Langr posted above.

Comment: @ I did. The problem is solved when I run the code in the terminal by using the ./filename command. However, it still gives errors when running by coderunner extension in vscode.

Comment: Then there is still some difference somewhere in how the code runner invokes the compiler and how you do it from the command line. If you have the time to spend on it, it would be really instructive for you to try to figure this out. If you are under time pressure, I'd just let good enough be for now and continue building via the manual process.

Comment: Why don't you just initaliase the variable with equal sign?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to run via the Code Runner extension, you should also make sure that the extension also compiles the program according to a standard post C++11. To do this:

1. Go to the extensions tab on the left panel and find the Extension Settings within the Settings icon next to Code Runner.
2. Search for "Executor Map" and click "Edit in settings.json".
3. You should be able to see the list of default commands used to run programs in different languages. Here, find the line for C++ and add the flag "-std=C++17" or anything of the form C++XX where XX denotes a valid C++ standard post (and including) 2011.
4. Save the file and run Code Runner.

[Code Runner Directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02gqd.png)

Answer (score -1):

In order to initialize a variable with {} you must say it is *=* {}.

Like this:

```cpp
int x = {3}; //you wouldn't really do this for simple variable though I don't think since you can just say int x = 3;
//or if you are making a custom object you might say:
MyObject object = {"apples", 3, "red"};
// to set the variables inside the object. in the order they are declared.
```

I hope this answers your question!