# Error: This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to compile a project that includes the eigen library and I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/--/--/--/Eigen/Core:19,
             from /home/--/--/--/Eigen/Geometry:11,
             from /usr/include/rl-0.7.0/rl/math/Transform.h:34,
             from /home/--/--/--/example.cpp:2:
/home/--/--/--/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:674:2: error: #error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
674 | #error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
  |  ^~~~~
```

I am using:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Cmake 3.16.3
- VSCode Compiler GCC 10.3.1
- Eigen 3.4.90

The problem seems to be related to these lines in Macros.h file:

```
// The macros EIGEN_HAS_CXX?? defines a rough estimate of available c++ features
// but in practice we should not rely on them but rather on the availability of
// individual features as defined later.
// This is why there is no EIGEN_HAS_CXX17.
#if EIGEN_MAX_CPP_VER<14 || EIGEN_COMP_CXXVER<14 || (EIGEN_COMP_MSVC && EIGEN_COMP_MSVC < 1900) || \
   (EIGEN_COMP_ICC && EIGEN_COMP_ICC < 1500) || (EIGEN_COMP_NVCC && EIGEN_COMP_NVCC < 80000) ||     \
   (EIGEN_COMP_CLANG && ((EIGEN_COMP_CLANG<309) || (defined(__apple_build_version__) && (__apple_build_version__ < 9000000)))) || \
   (EIGEN_COMP_GNUC_STRICT && EIGEN_COMP_GNUC<51)
#error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
#endif
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Maybe a bad guess but possibly you'd need to use a newer C++ standard to compile. You might try to run the cmake config with `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14` or `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Lala5th suggested, by changing the C++ standard the problem is solved.

I have modified the CMakeLists.txt:

From:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

To:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

(It also works with 14)

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, Macros.h file tells us the problem is with compiler version.

### VSCode compiler

GCC 10 definitely has support for c++17. It means that you should change it's starting flags. In settings.json file add this lines:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
},
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131548/10962180).

### Standard Bash's g++

Use g++ with `-std=c++17` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted two days on this trying the accepted answers but below thing worked for me. This Faced the same issue when i was building opencv with c++

As Suggested by @Lala5th use the

cmake with -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14 or -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 when you build the project

i.e instead of `cmake pathToFile` use `cmake pathToFile -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17`