# Eigen: This Compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen, Linux c++14

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, eigen, eigen3

I am attempting to build a large project (Amino) which has dependencies on the Open Motion Planning Library and Eigen. It is built with a `makefile.am`, with a makefile created after running `autoreconf` and `./configure`. Running `make` results in about 20000 lines of errors, starting with after a couple "In file included from" lines:

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:711:2: error: #error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
```

What I expected: `make` to run to completion successfully
What I saw: Many errors. All of them appear to be directly related to failure to read/compile Eigen, and none to the library specifically.

What I tried to resolve the problem (all did not resolve/resulted in the same error):

(1)
Changing the final line in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ompl.pc` from:

`Cflags: -std=c++14 -I${includedir} -I/usr/include`
to:
`Cflags: -std=c++14 -I${includedir} -I/usr/include/eigen3`

as per the instructions on http://amino.golems.org/installation.html

(2)
Changing the cflags to -std=c++11 (resulting in an error on the `./configure` step) and `-std=c++17` (identical error to the default)

(3) Removing the `-std=` argument entirely to completely match the above instructions

(4) Installing Eigen from source versus the apt repository

(5) Checking my compiler and Eigen versions to see if any were especially old or especially new (they were not)

UPDATE

(6) changing the following line in the file `configure` :

`for ac_arg in '' -std=gnu++11 -std=gnu++0x -std=c++11 -std=c++0x -qlanglvl=extended0x -AA`

to
`for ac_arg in '' -std=gnu++11 -std=gnu++0x -std=c++14 -std=c++0x -qlanglvl=extended0x -AA`

The idea being that this would ensure the compilation was done with c++14 rather than c++11. It also did not work.

(7) changing the line further to remove the `-std=c++0x` portion, in case that was overwriting the former `-std` argument. No effect.

A few other answers exist that are similar to this issue, most notably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71953477/error-this-compiler-appears-to-be-too-old-to-be-supported-by-eigen) question discussing an identical error, but they all assume use of CMake.

System information:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

Eigen version: libeigen3-dev (3.3.7-2), installed from apt repository

Compiler: g++, using `gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1)`

Update: As per question 1, line 711 in `Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h` is as follows:

```
// The macros EIGEN_HAS_CXX?? defines a rough estimate of available c++ features
// but in practice we should not rely on them but rather on the availability of
// individual features as defined later.
// This is why there is no EIGEN_HAS_CXX17.
#if EIGEN_MAX_CPP_VER < 14 || EIGEN_COMP_CXXVER < 14 || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_MSVC && EIGEN_COMP_MSVC < 1900) || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_ICC && EIGEN_COMP_ICC < 1500) || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_NVCC && EIGEN_COMP_NVCC < 80000) || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_CLANG_STRICT && EIGEN_COMP_CLANG < 390) || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_CLANGAPPLE && EIGEN_COMP_CLANGAPPLE < 9000000) || \
  (EIGEN_COMP_GNUC_STRICT && EIGEN_COMP_GNUC < 510)
#error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
#endif
```

As per question 2, the make command with `V=1` outputs the following:

```
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./include -I./src/mac  -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wconversion -Wextra  -g -O2 -MT src/rx/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.lo -MD -MP -MF src/rx/.deps/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.Tpo -c -o src/rx/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.lo `test -f 'src/rx/amino_fcl.cpp' || echo './'`src/rx/amino_fcl.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./include -I./src/mac -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wconversion -Wextra -g -O2 -MT src/rx/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.lo -MD -MP -MF src/rx/.deps/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.Tpo -c src/rx/amino_fcl.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/rx/.libs/libamino_collision_la-amino_fcl.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/common/types.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/math/bv/AABB.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/geometry/collision_geometry.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/narrowphase/collision_object.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/broadphase/broadphase_collision_manager.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/broadphase/broadphase_SSaP.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/fcl/fcl.h:45,
                 from src/rx/amino_fcl.cpp:53:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:711:2: error: #error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
  711 | #error This compiler appears to be too old to be supported by Eigen
```

Someone suggested below that the standard might be getting lowered to C++11, and the above command corroborates this.

Update/Solution:

I followed a suggestion to uninstall the apt versions of Eigen and OMPL and install them from source. This worked and I was able to build the project successfully. I am not sure why, as the major versions were the same as far as I could tell, but I am not complaining.

Comment: If you open the `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h` file, and look around line `711`, what kind of check is done to check the compiler version? What compiler and what version more specifically is it looking for? How is it looking for that compiler and its version? Perhaps the checks are flawed and doesn't properly check for too new versions?

Comment: Make should also print the compile commands, right? Please post the call that causes the issue

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edits made to address your question. Ditto for Homer 512 but I cannot @ two people at once.

Comment: Hmm, I'd really like to see the proper command that is being executed. Try `make VERBOSE=1` Right now my working hypothesis is that something in the build file removes the c++-standard or there are conflicting compile parameters that demote the standard to C++-11 or below

Comment: @Homer512 I don't have the knowledge to fix the error precisely, but the command when using `V=1` (not `VERBOSE=1` in this case, as it depends on how the Makefile is made) does say "c++11" in it, which was recently deprecated by Eigen. This suggests that your standard demotion theory is on the money.

Comment: @Homer512 See above. I fixed the issue (or rather someone else did via a suggestion that I would not have thought to do, since it violates the Amino install instructions fairly blatantly). Hooray for idiosyncratic computer behavior!