# Is there any shortcut way to initialize char array which is allocated by new keyword

Tags: c++

Like in SMA we initialize char array as char arr[]={"Text"};
How to initialize char type array in DMA i.e, char *ptr = new char[10];
now i don't want to use loop or multiple lines !

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char *ptr = new char[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; cout << ptr[i], i++)
ptr[i] = getch();

cout<<ptr;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::string`?

Comment: The better and simpler approach is to use `std::string` instead of dynamic allocation `std::string str = "Text";`

Comment: i wanted to know about arrays allocated by new keyword explicity !

Comment: Who taught you to write the for loop like this? The `cout` statement should not be inside the `()`.

Comment: just to print characters !

Comment: @TufailGulzar *i wanted to know about arrays allocated by new keyword !* -- First, the comment section is for comments, not for answers.   We are commenting on your code, and we have no idea if you were aware of the `std::string` class or not.  Second, your code using `new[]` is discouraged in this day and age of C++.  The `std::string` class has now been part of C++ for almost 25 years now.  There is no reason to be writing `new char[]` in this manner.  Third, your code is not correct in that it does not issue a call to `delete[]`, thus creating a memory leak (even if this is a toy program).

Comment: ok thanks  sir . Sorry i just wanted to know if any method exists like i came to know we can use strcpy()

Comment: @TufailGulzar Use `char *ptr = new char[10]{"Text"};` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74969960/12002570). See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GYx6raon5)

Comment: Given `#include<conio.h>`, it seems you are using C++/2e (1989).  There have been improvements and changes to C++ since then.  What was best practices for C++/2e are not necessarily best practices with modern C++17.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcpy` to copy a string into a character array that has been allocated using `new`:

```
char *ptr = new char[10];
strcpy(ptr, "Text");
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is still a loop, it's just that the loop is hidden behind a function name

Comment: More importantly, this is not "initialization". So technically this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're explicitly asking about "initializing", you can do this:

```
char *ptr = new char[10]{"Text"};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GYx6raon5)

Comment: Already tried not working try anywhere else besides above mentioned link. check here : https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @TufailGulzar The site you're referring to probably uses old compiler or c++ standard. The program should work with new C++ standard and compiler. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b9ExKnKsG). It works with all compiler in the site I mentioned.

Comment: Ok thanks sir  actually i tried it already in vs code but didn't work out may be i need install latest gcc compiler. Your code showing error: main.cpp:5:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: @TufailGulzar This might help. [How to enable C++17 support in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension) and [How to Setup VS Code For C++ 14 /C ++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116344/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-c-14-c-17)