# C++23 Language Features Syntax Highlighting in VS-Code not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, c++23

For compilation I use mingw-64 with the gnu (g++) compiler. My *CMakeLists.txt* contains the following:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.8)
project(Program)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(Program
  src/main.cc
)
```

My *compile_commands.json* generated by CMake contains the following:

```json
[
{
  "directory": "C:/dev/Project/build",
  "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe   -g -std=gnu++23 -o CMakeFiles\\Project.dir\\src\\main.cc.obj -c C:\\dev\\Project\\src\\main.cc",
  "file": "C:/dev/AoC/src/day11/main.cc",
  "output": "CMakeFiles/Project.dir/src/main.cc.obj"
}
]
```

My *c_cpp_properties.json* inside the *.vscode* folder contains the following:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "minGW++",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu23",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Some simple C++ code I wrote inside main.cc:

```c++
struct operatorTest {
  size_t operator[](size_t a, size_t b) { return a + b; }
  // too many parameters for this operator function
};

int main() {
  operatorTest test;
  std::printf("Test Result: %d; C++ Version: %d", test[2, 4], __cplusplus);
  // error squiggles under "test[2, 4]" no operator "[]" matches these operands
}
```

This code compiled and executes successfully. It prints the expected
`Test Result: 6; C++ Version: 202100`.
The problem is that VS-Code doesn't recognize the C++23 syntax, resulting in error squiggles.

I tried getting rid of any of the MSVC settings, the C++17 settings, the old CMake Path and added a new Config as seen above. The interesting thing is, that if I compile the project the error squiggles disappear for a brief amount of time and then reappear, signalling that CMake thinks no error occurred.

Comment: show output of `g++ --version` and also add the version number of your VS Code C/C++ extension

Comment: also copy the problem descriptions as JSON from the Problems panel and paste them into your question post in a code block

Comment: See if this helps:[How to Setup VS Code For C++ 14 /C ++17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600447/12002570)